# Where is the bed you rent in vault 21?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've run around and around the entire vault and can't seem to find the rented room ("use key" never shows up). In addition, I've slept in every bed I can find but none of them will heal me (I'm on hardcore mode).

Can someone give me directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_player_character_housing#Notes) :

*Sarah Weintraub, the gift shop manager of Vault 21, located in the New Vegas Strip, will rent out a room to the player. The cost starts at 100 caps, but she will give increasing discounts as you deliver her Vault suits. If the player passes a speech check, gains rep with the Strip, or brings Sarah enough Vault suits, she will offer the room at 40 caps. If the player brings more Vault suits to her, she will offer the room at 10 caps. Upon giving her enough Vault suits, the room will become free and she will have sex with you if asked. **Having sex with her is the only way the room provides a well rested bonus**.*

Have fun :D

[image: map]

*map from [GameBanshee](http://www.gamebanshee.com/falloutnewvegas/locations/vault21.php)*

*Sarah is in 1, the rented room in 3*

Comment: This might explain why the room does not have owned-bed effects (though it only mentions the well rested bonus), however it doesn't explain where it actually is, so I can't accept your answer in it's current state. I made a thread on the fallout subreddit and it appears the room is next to sarah's room (the locked one), but I couldn't verify it because nothing about the room suggests that it is actually the room you rented (Otherwise I would have made an answer myself). Nevertheless, I think he's correct because the location makes sense (being next door to sarah's).

Comment: @user2345397 I added a nice picture. Satisfied ? :p

Comment: Yes, the picture is very nice touch. I'm surprised I didn't find this myself.

Comment: Well, I'm not at work right now, so I have a little more time for searching ^^